# Delete from table with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Morning,

I have three tables:

Table: debtors

```
id           -    INT(11)
type         -    ENUM('c', 'p')
```

Table: companies

```
id           -    INT(11)
debtor_id    -    INT(11)
and a lot of other fields for companies
```

Table: private_individuals

```
id           -    INT(11)
debtor_id    -    INT(11)
and a lot of other fields for private individuals
```

Foreign KEY SQL for companies(same is used for private individuals):

```
INDEX `fk_private_individual_debtors1` (`debtor_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_private_individual_debtors1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`debtor_id` )
    REFERENCES `application_user`.`debtors` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

When I delete a company or private individual I want the debtor to be deleted as well and it should work the other way around aswell(delete a debtor and the company or private individual is deleted aswell).

I'm thinking to do this with a trigger but I suppose there is a better way to do it..

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Not a good idea. While deleting a debtor may occasionally happen, I doubt that a major bank would want to be wiped out of existence because one of their loans was discharged.

Comment: Deleting a debtor, company or private individual is not possible(hiding is...) within the regular GUI or with the regular MySQL user.. So mistakes by making a wrong click or something like that are not likely to happen.. But when a company is deleted it is not correct to let the debtor stay because a debtor is either a company or private individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Delete a debtor and the company or private individual is deleted as
>   well:

This can be done by `ON DELETE CASCADE`. You specify this when you define the foreign key, and applies to all deletes on the table. You cannot mention this at the indivudual DELETE level. See [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) in the MySql manual 
Remember this is dangerous in most cases and you are better off having this logic in your application code.

> When I delete a company or private individual I want the debtor to be
>   deleted as well

This is not directly possible. You have built a foreign key relationship between a company and a debtor but there can be more than one company associated to the debtor. There is nothing in the foreign key that prevents this. You may have additional application logic (in a procedure, in your java/C# code, in triggers) but there is nothing in the foreign key level at all.
So since this is acheived by additional application logic your deletion also will need additional application logic.
One another point to note is: you should delete a [arent only if all of its child records are deleted.